# Monitoring Spark-Shell or PySpark-Shell sessions on Dataproc cluster

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I understand there are answers for accessing Spark [Job Driver Output](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/driver-output) and [Hadoop Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836067/in-dataproc-how-can-i-access-the-spark-and-hadoop-job-history) from a Dataproc cluster, along with [Output from Dataproc Spark job in Google Cloud Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186511/output-from-dataproc-spark-job-in-google-cloud-logging). Thanks for these.

However, I am also interested in viewing logs for *incomplete* Spark applications, such as an interactive `pyspark-shell` or `spark-shell` sessions—both by:

1. using the same web interfaces, along with possibly
2. accessing the the raw session output (a log file on local fs or hdfs?)

During a Spark shell session, while I can view the session as an *incomplete application*, the UI provides no such information across the *Jobs*, *Stages* and *Tasks* tabs when I am executing commands in the REPL. This can be easily replicated like:

```
# Launch Dataproc cluster
>> gcloud beta dataproc clusters create $DATAPROC_CLUSTER_NAME

# SSH to master node:
>> gcloud compute ssh "root@$DATAPROC_CLUSTER_NAME-m"

# Launch a Spark shell (e.g., Python) 
>> pyspark
```

I'm able to see the Spark session as an incomplete application (as noted above), and can execute a basic Spark job (with a `collect` action), like:

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x: x + 1)
>>> rdd2.collect()
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> rdd2.persist()
PythonRDD[1] at collect at <stdin>:1
```

But this results in no information across any of the *Jobs*, *Stages*, or *Storage* tabs: [see Spark Job History UI screen grab (blank)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2hYJ.png).

To emphasize: when submitting jobs via the Dataproc API, however, these tabs *do show* all the expected job history.

Any tips on where I can access such output / job history from the Spark shell session? Many thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dataproc only provides driver output for Dataproc jobs, that is drivers submitted through the API (usually via the Cloud SDK or the Developer Console). To run spark-shell, you have to ssh into the cluster and run the shell yourself, which will not be tracked as job. It is however still tracked in Web UIs and you can capture the console output yourself.

1. The Spark History Server only updates when the application finishes. For a live Spark Web UI:

   a. Go to the YARN ResourceMangers's Web UI [as documented here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/cluster-web-interfaces#available_interfaces_wzxhzdk5wzxhzdk6)

   b. Find your application (it is probably on top, RUNNING, and name     PySparkShell)

   c. Click on ApplicationMaster in the final column under Tracking UI.

   d. You should see the live Spark Web UI for your application.

   In general, I would always recommend viewing Spark and MapReduce jobs through the ResourceManager's WebUI, because it has links to both the currently running and completed job histories.
2. You can capture the output of the shell into a local log using something like `spark-shell |& tee -a shell.log`. If you only want log records (and not print statements), you could also [use log4j to configure a local file log](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging).

Comment: Thank you @PatrickClay, this was helpful. The explanation on driver output for Dataproc jobs vs. `spark-shell` was helpful, make sense. And yes, that's right about having to execute an action—but stating it is helpful in the context of this question. It makes me realize I should be more explicit about the workflow I am performing, and the result (as I  *am* executing an action from `spark-shell` but no output in Spark history UI, as described above). I am going to update the question with this to better explain, because I suspect there is something that I am missing. :)

Comment: Hi @patrick, I was able to update the question to also contain steps to replicate the UI containing no job, stage, or storage info. Hope it make it clearer what I am asking for help with in regards to the UI.  thanks. :)

Comment: The screen capture showed me which server you were looking at, and did make it clearer. Sorry to answer the wrong question initially. Hope that helps.

Comment: This did help and I was finally able to find the Spark Job History UI for the running spark shell session, thank you so much! I had previously worked primarily with Spark Standalone mode, and haven't had too much experience with YARN, so I didn't know where to look. :)